# NgIf and zero: Why is the template not being rendered?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-template

I have the following observable on and Angular component:

```
count$: Observable<number>;

this.count$ = this.getCount();
```

By using the following I get the value 0 (Zero);

```
this.count$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

On the template I have:

```
<a routerLink="/dash" *ngIf="(count$ | async)">
  <ng-container *ngIf="count$ | async as count">
    Count: {{count}}
  </ng-container>
</a>
```

If `count$` is 1 I get `Count: 1` but if `count$` is 0 the content `Count: 0` is not even rendered.

Any idea why?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19364

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank your for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19364), this is the expected behavior. `NgIf` coerces the given expression into a `boolean` value. If the expression evaluates into a [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value (values that are translated into *false*) then the content wont be rendered.

The following are all the values that javascript currently translates to *false*:

```
if (false)
if (null)
if (undefined)
if (0)
if (NaN)
if ('')
if ("")
if (``)
```

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone is looking for a workaround, this so stupid but it works:

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="{ len: count$ | async } as ctx">
      <ng-container *ngIf="ctx.len !== null"        
          {{ ctx.len }} 
       </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
```

Explanation:

1. Capture `count` as `len` inside of an object called `ctx`
2. Because `*ngIf` is now looking at an object, instead of the value, it will evaluate as truthy and render the `ng-container`
3. Now we check whether we got an actual value or not with `ctx.len !== null`
4. We can access the value using `ctx.len`

Answer (score 3):

You're using an ngIf, means you are doing a conditional display of your value. When the value is 0, your condition evaluates to false and thus won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases:

```
    if (false)
    if (null)
    if (undefined)
    if (0)
    if (NaN)
    if ('')
    if ("")
    if (``)
```

These are all falsy as stated above, here is my suggestion:
By using a *pipe(map())* to convert it to string, that way '0' is not falsy and it can still be used with number pipe, etc.

Hope this helps some else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).